# Globalize Silverlight Preloader

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, preloader

how can I globalize silverlight's preloader animation? I have added animation by adding a xaml file in the folder with the aspx page using the following tag:

```
<param name="splashscreensource"value="AppLoaderScr.xaml"/>
```

I know how to do this in normal silverlight xaml but how do I do it when the xaml is in a web application project?

Thanks in anticipation!

Answer (score 2):

You could make the aspx page detect the culture and then put a different value in the attribute for example...

French

```
<param name="splashscreensource"value="AppLoaderScr.fr.xaml"/>
```

English

```
<param name="splashscreensource"value="AppLoaderScr.en.xaml"/>
```